# sshfs or fish:// with root (ssh) login disabled

Tags: linux, scp, sshfs, fish

The server does not allow root login from ssh. I can, however, login as my username and su to root (I know the root pw).

Is there a way to use the fish:// protocol or sshfs or some other way to mount the remote server folders locally without allowing root login trough ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sshfs:// or fish:// to mount remote directories that your user has access to. You can't access any directories that you would first have to su to root to get to in a regular SSH session.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't login as root, you can't expect to have the same levels of access, but you can use sshfs with any user who has ssh and sftp/scp access to the server. You could add the user to the group that has access to the directories, and that should provide some if not most of the access you need.